# Running external Java Process with ProcessBuilder and give heap size

Tags: java, processbuilder, heap-size

I didn't figured out yet how to run a external Java Application with a specify heap size in a ProcessBuilder.

The ProcessBuilder is just that simple as it should:

```java
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-jar", jar);
Process p = pb.start();
```

But, how can I give the Process a specify heap size.
f.E `java -jar -Xms1048M -Xmx2048M somejar.jar`

Thank you Guys very much :D
LG

Answer (score 4):

You can easily add the options when creating the ProcessBuilder:

```java
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-jar", "-Xms1048M", "-Xmx2048M", jar);
Process p = pb.start();
```

You can use a list or a string array containing the program and its arguments, as described in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.util.List)).